# how to skip empty lines from a txt file with php

Tags: php

I am using this code to delete an email address form a txt file named `database-email.txt`:

```
// unsubscribe
if (isset($_POST['email-unsubscribe'])) {     
$emailToRemove = $_POST['email-unsubscribe'] . ',';
$content = file_get_contents('database-email.txt');
if($content = str_replace($emailToRemove, '',  $content)) {
    echo "$emailToRemove successfully removed!";
}
else {
    echo "$emailToRemove could not be removed!";
}
file_put_contents('database-email.txt',  $content);
}

?>
```

My txt file looks like this:

```
annelore@mail.ru,
francien@live.nl,
frans@moonen.nl,
harry@hotmail.com,

jannie@live.nl,
jeanette.schmitz@live.nl,

johnny.doe@live.nl,
```

I tried this to skip all the empty lines in the `txt` file but without success:

```
file_put_contents('database-email.txt',  implode(PHP_EOL, file($content, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)));
```

How can i skip the empty lines from `database-email.txt` ?

Comment: you could change how you read the file http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Comment: `$emailToRemove = $_POST['email-unsubscribe'] . ',' . PHP_EOL;`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
file_put_contents('database-email.txt',
    str_replace("\n\n", "\n", file_get_contents('database-email.txt'))
);
```

**NB** `\n` depends of how you inserts lines in your file. It could be `\r\n` or `PHP_EOL`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `file()` function with `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` options to read the file as an array. Then use the `array_search()` function to search for the element and remove it if it's present. You can then implode the array and write it back to file.

Don't use your `str_replace` approach, it's buggy. Imagine this is your file:

```
abdc@domain.com
```

If you remove `dc@domain.com` you will get:

```
ab
```

You are not checking that you are replacing an entire email.

I would also suggest that you remove the commas, you don't need them if you have only one email per line.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
file_put_contents('database-email.txt', implode('', file($content, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)));
```

Alternatively:

```
file_put_contents('database-email.txt',preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~',"\r\n",trim($content)));
```